# Change background color in CSS using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using CSS, I'm trying to set the background color of each element to a random color on hover:

```
:hover {
    background-color: "getRandom()";
}
```

However, it doesn't appear to be possible to put a JavaScript function call here. Is there any alternative approach that would work?

Here's the page I'm working on:  http://jsfiddle.net/FwKqq/3/

Comment: You can't use JavaScript within CSS like that. What is your question?

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm trying to set an element's background color to the output of `getRandom()`, which returns a random color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery code:

```
$("*").hover(
    function(event) {
        $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());
    },
    function (event) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
);
```

(You should also remove the `:hover` css element)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqSgq/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('*').hover(
        function() { $(this).css('background-color', getRandom()); }, 
        function() {$(this).css('background-color', '#FFF');}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeBackground(color) {
   document.body.style.background = //here apply background colour;
}
```

call this function in `hover` event

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FwKqq/4/

You need to set the background-color when the call starts and ends like this:

```
$("*").hover(
    function(event) {
        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
    },
    function (event) {
       $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure cross-browser Javascript with [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RFEXP/1/):

```
var bgColor;
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            bgColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
            this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }, false);
        els[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            bgColor = '#FFFFFF';
            this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        }, false);
    } else {
        els[i].attachEvent('mouseover', function () {
            e.stopPropagation();
            bgColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
            this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        });
        els[i].attachEvent('mouseout', function () {
            e.stopPropagation();
            bgColor = '#FFFFFF';
            this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        });
    }
}
```

Random background code from here: http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/